# Raspberry Pi - HDMI damaged?

Tags: raspbian, hdmi

My Raspberry Pi have some strange display output (as seen in bottom right corner of attached image). Yesterday all worked fine.

Today I went to an other place and connected the Pi to the display. First get an pink colored screen, rebooted, after that get no screen at all.
Went home, get no screen, too.

So edited the boot.config via ssh and setted the hdmi strength to 9. Now I get a screen, but with artifacts. If I set the hdmi strength even lower as 9, the effect gets stronger or no display output at all.

Should I send the Pi back to Amazon or is it a software Problem?

[image: Raspberry Pi display output]

Comment: Did this "other place" involve another cable, or the same one as at the original place?

Comment: Yes, another cable was used. But back home I was forced to decrease hdmi strength to use the pi at the original place, too.